# keep asking for a number until a even number is entered

Tags: javascript

in this assignment we are to prompt for a box and type in a number. If it is  even an alert comes back and says it is even, if odd and alert comes back and says odd. I got that working, but the part that I am stuck on is we need the prompt box to keep coming back until an even number is entered. Here is the code that I have used so far:

```
<script>

    var number = parseInt(prompt("Please put a number between 1 and 50"));


 if (number % 2 == 0) {
     alert("Your number is Even!");
}

 else {
      alert("Your number is Odd!");
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Google for "javascript loops".

Comment: Put the code in a function. If the number is odd, call the function again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a do/while loop

```
var number;

do {
    number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter an even number"), 10);
} while ( number % 2 );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/umzqv6m1/)

Comment: I'd call it a *do* loop. And `while (number % 2)` is less to type. Down voters are restless…

Comment: @RobG - sure, why not, I just used the OP's example and kept the check for zero